# Include $or in $match of aggregate doesn't work in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Items.aggregate([ 
   {$match: { expiry_date: { $gt: moment().toDate() } }}
])
```

How can I include $or in aggregate's match? Above query is fine, I can get the 
items that has expiry_date greater than today.

But when I do the opposite

```
Items.aggregate([ 
   {$match: { expiry_date: { $lt: moment().toDate() } }}
])
```

I can't retrieve anything, because some data their expiry_date is equal to null, which means expiry date is optional.

**To get
1. item that has not expired
2. item that has no expiry_date field**

I think I have to use $or to filter out expiry_date and retrieve those item which doesn't have expiry_date set.

I tried this but doesn't work, why I still got empty array?

```
Items.aggregate([ 
 {$match: { expiry_date: {
  $or: [{$lt: moment().toDate()}, {$eq: null}]
  } }}
])
```

Comment: [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is a "top level" condition. Instead of applying to a "property" you supply an "array of conditions" including the specific "property/properties" to which they apply.

Comment: @NeilLunn but how to put it in $match?

Comment: `$match` is just the same as ``find()``. i.e `{ "$match": { "$or": [{ "expiry_date": { "$lt": moment().toDate() } },{ "expiry_date": null }] }}`. All covered on the duplicate question and answer and in the documentation also linked.